# library mercado pago for react native

Tags: react-native, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

I'm trying to use the paid market in an application written in react native, however, I did not find any library that worked correctly today.

I tried using [BlackBoxVision library](https://github.com/BlackBoxVision/react-native-mercado-paycheckout) and [line64](https://github.com/line64/react-native-checkout-mercadopaago), however, neither of them even compiled.

I'm also open to new ideas, like using a webview, things like that, but so far, none of the attempts has led anywhere.

Comment: do you solve it? im about to clone that repos and fix the compile errors

Comment: We started to correct some errors, but for a project time, we ended up abandoning the package and started for another approach

Comment: wich approach? please tell me more